# (PyQt and PySide) QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory doesn't work on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

This code works perfectly fine on mac, after clicking on the button, the dir dialog show up. On Windows, it freezes after the button clicks (refer to the picture).

Here is my code:

```
import os 
import sys
from Pyside import QtGui

class OpenDir(QtGui.QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
      super(OpenDir, self).__init__()
      self.initUI()

   def initUI(self):
      self.openDir = QtGui.QPushButton('Dialog', self)
      self.openDir.move(20, 20);
      self.openDir.clicked.connect(self.open_dir)
      self.show()

   def open_dir(self):
      self.filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 
                                             "open dir", os.getcwd())

def main():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   ui = OpenDir()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Updated:

[Error after clicking on dialog button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2x0G.png)

Comment: I am unable to replicate this in either PyQt4 or 1.2.2. When I click the button, it opens a dialog with the title bar set to `open dir`

Comment: I can replicate this in PyQt4 on my mac and it works as a charm. It doesn't work on Windows either PySide or PyQt. @Andy

Comment: What versions of Python and PyQt/Pyside are you running in windows? What version of windows?

Comment: I use Anaconda 2.7.8 Python, PyQt4 and Windows 7 enterprise. @Andy I'm wondering whether this may cause from the Python distribution i'm using.

Comment: Unlikely. I'm using Anaconda as well. Python 2.7.9, PyQt 4.8.6, PySide 1.2.2. Only difference is I have Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. @ekhumoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by **installing Python 3.4.3**. So I assume this must be compatibility between PyQt/PySide and Python distributions (Anaconda).